# Kotlin Android Extensions accessing text views

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

So I am teaching myself android development and I am simply trying to update a text view with the results from a Volley get call. I have looked at other stackoverflow threads and kotlin tutorials but nothing seems to be working.

I have 3 main files I am dealing

activity_main.xml with these views

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:text="Title"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/story"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="Story Contents"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/message" />
```

MainActivity.kt

```
    import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import <GetRequest>

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_home -> {

                val getRequestUtils = GetRequestUtils()
                getRequestUtils.makeGetRequest(this)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_dashboard -> {
                message.setText(R.string.title_dashboard)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    }}
```

GetRequestUtils.kt

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import <Book>
import <R>

class GetRequestUtils : Activity(){
    val parseResponseUtil = ParseResponseUtil()

    fun makeGetRequest(context: Context) {
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, <Get Request URL>, Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            val book = parseResponseUtil.getBookComponents(response)
            message?.text = book.title
            story?.text = book.story
        }, Response.ErrorListener { Book("Something went wrong", "Something went wrong", "Something went wrong")})
        queue.add(stringRequest)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

**Note some of the imports have been replaced with  as the imports have my name in them.

Whenever I make this call I get an error stating the

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

From my research this is because the view is not created or accessible by the time the get call has been made, but when I attempt to set the message and story textViews inside the onCreate of GetRequestUtils,

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    message.setText("HERE")
    story.setText("HERE2")
}
```

the textViews are not updated so not I am not sure I am even properly accessing the textViews on the activity_main.xml.

Can someone please help me see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: May I know what .kt is this? From what file message.setText("HERE")
    story.setText("HERE2")

Comment: @Ticherhaz `.kt` is the extension of a Kotlin file

Comment: it is from MainActivity.kt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider each Activity as a screen, because you has attach `R.layout.activity_main` xml file with `MainActivity` so you should not attach it to anywhere else (unless you want to create another screen with the same layout). `GetRequestUtils` is a class used to get data so it should not extend `Activity`. To return value after getting data from API, you can use an interface callback

```
    class GetRequestUtils {

        interface Callback {
            fun onDone(book: Book)
        }

        val parseResponseUtil = ParseResponseUtil()

        fun makeGetRequest(context: Context, callback: Callback) {
            val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
            val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, <Get Request URL>, Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                val book = parseResponseUtil.getBookComponents(response)
                callback.onDone(book)
            }, Response.ErrorListener { 
                val book = Book("Something went wrong", "Something went wrong", "Something went wrong")
                callback.onDone(book)
            })
            queue.add(stringRequest)
        }
    }
```

In `MainActivity`, set value to TextView when get callback from the Request Util

```
R.id.navigation_home -> {
    val getRequestUtils = GetRequestUtils()
    getRequestUtils.makeGetRequest(this, object : GetRequestUtils.Callback {
        override fun onDone(book: Book) {
            message?.text = book.title
            story?.text = book.story
        })
    return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
}
```

Comment: This worked! I appreciate your easy to understand explanation as to why you made the changes you did. Thank you!